# React-native : Compiling Android error on processReleaseResources step

Tags: android, react-native, android-resources

I m trying to compiling my app for android with react-native 0.25 ( i know that s not the last one but i started the project a long time ago now ) .

I recently changed one of my assets from "downArrow.jpg" to "downArrow.png" .
From this time, i can t compile for release mode because i m facing the following issue with gradle :

```
18:04:27.715 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Unknown source file : res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_downarrow.png:0: error: Resource entry assets_downarrow is already defined.
18:04:27.726 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Unknown source file : res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_downarrow.jpg:0: Originally defined here.
```

since i have no folder "drawable-mdpi-v4" in the android resources folder i guess react native push my assets into this folder but the problem is i only have the "downArrow.png" left, the jpg one has already delete from the git.

I restarted the react-native packager and also ran the following command : 
    cd Android && ./gradlew clean build assemble

but the problem still remain.

any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay So finally launched Android studio and trigger the clean / build / invalidate cache actions and everyrhing works fine now

Answer (score 1):

I solved by: `cd android/ && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

Solved,
That means you have `downarrow.jpg` and `downarrow.png`, You should remove or rename one of them because drawable is handling images without file extension.